# How to notify the widget class to show Snackbar?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

In my controller class I've a method to create a category and save that category into db. I call crateCategory method from CreateCategoryUseCase class from CategoryController class. The method returns Failure if there's any exception and id if storing is successful. Now I want to show a snackbar when there's failure or success. How can I notify the ui to show the snackbar. I'm not using any third party package like riverpod or bloc. Here's my code:

```
    class CategoriesController {
  final _todoStreamController = StreamController<List<CategoryModel>>();

  Stream<List<CategoryModel>> get categoryStream =>
      _todoStreamController.stream;

  final FetchCategoryUseCase fetchCategoryUseCase;
  final CreateCategoryUseCase createCategoryUseCase;


  CategoriesController({
    required this.createCategoryUseCase,
    required this.fetchCategoryUseCase,
  }) {
    _fetchCategories();
  }

  void _fetchCategories() {
    fetchCategoryUseCase.fetchCategoriesStream().fold((failure) {
      _todoStreamController.addError(failure.message);
    }, (stream) {
      stream.listen((categories) {
        _todoStreamController.add(categories);
      });
    });
  }

  void createCategory(String categoryName) {
    createCategoryUseCase.createCategory(categoryName).fold(
      (failure) {
        
      },
      (id) {
        debugPrint('Category created with id: $id');
      },
    );
  }

  void dispose() {
    _todoStreamController.close();
  }
}
```

here's my ui code:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});


  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller =
        CategoriesControllerProvider.of(context).categoriesController;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
        child: StreamBuilder<List<CategoryModel>>(
          stream: controller.categoryStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final categories = snapshot.data!;
              return categories.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: categories.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final category = snapshot.data![index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            category.title,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : const Center(
                      child: Text('No Categories'),
                    );
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              } else {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showAdaptiveDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Add Category'),
                content: TextFormField(
                  controller: textController,
                ),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.createCategory(textController.text);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Add'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    CategoriesControllerProvider.of(context).categoriesController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass buildContext to createCategory method and show snack bar, so your method would be like this:

```
  void createCategory(String categoryName, final BuildContext context) {
createCategoryUseCase.createCategory(categoryName).fold(
  (failure) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('failure message')),
    );
  },
  (id) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('success message')),
    );
    debugPrint('Category created with id: $id');
  },
);
}
```

Comment: You should never pass a BuildContext to a Controller.

Comment: BuildContext could be passed through Constructor and method both but it will be bad  practice that's why I'm avoiding that.